# Optional.get() versus overloaded Optional.orElseThrow()

Tags: java, option-type, java-10

How can one avoid explicitly throwing an `Exception` while trying to get the value from an `Optional` or while making use of **[`Optional.get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#get--)**?

Currently, this is possibly safeguarded with the API `orElseThrow` as :

```
// exception could be replaced with any other
Integer opt = anyOddInStream.orElseThrow(
                           () -> new NoSuchElementException("No value present"));
```

and yet the directly implementing the `get` disappoints(when one might not be willing to explicitly throw an exception) while trying to access something like

```
// the following not only just fails but throws an exception as well
Integer previous = anyOddInStream.get();
```

What if one wants to make sure that the `Optional` either has a value and if it doesn't they wouldn't want to continue propagating `null` ahead?

Comment: @shmosel That does not matter. "NoSuchElementException if there is no value present" is the API. The point is that it is not the OP who throws the exception.

Comment: I absolutely never understood this addition, is that preparation to remove/deprecate `get`? I really wish @StuartMarks would come here...

Comment: @Eugene Brian already answered. But deprecating `get()` is still in the cards, though we have more work to do before proceeding. (Note also, the @-notification doesn't work unless that person has commented previously, so I didn't get a notification from your comment. I just happened across it because I monitor the `Optional` tag.)

Comment: This post is useful (I just used it as a dupe), but the question is *really* hard to read. Please try to make it clearer.

Comment: @shmosel Yes, there was a really fine margin at the time I'd asked this between what I thought the question should be and what the current overloaded implementation already provided. Actually, looking back, the question was just to seek the difference in using `get` vs `orElseThrow`. And honestly, as it stands today I myself feel that both of them leave the consumers in a troublesome situation. (opinion)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Java 8 was a huge improvement to the platform, but one of the few mistakes we made was the naming of `Optional.get()`, because the name just invites people to call it without calling `isPresent()`, undermining the whole point of using `Optional` in the first place.  (If this was the worst mistake we made in such a big release, then we did pretty well.)

During the Java 9 time frame, we proposed to deprecate `Optional.get()`, but the public response to that was ... let's say cold.  As a smaller step, we introduced `orElseThrow()` in 10 (see https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8140281) as a more transparently named synonym for the current pernicious behavior of `get()`.  IDEs warn on unconditional use of `get()`, but not on `orElseThrow()`, which is a step forward in teaching people to code better.  The question is, in a sense, a "glass half empty" view of the current situation; `get()` is still problematic.

We'd love to improve the situation further in future version, but it will probably take some time to bring more of the community around.

Comment: No better authoritative source than Java Language Architect Mr. Brian Goetz himself!!! imo `get()` should have been deprecated/removed with Java 11 so people would stop using it with `isPresent` which is unfortunately an attractive antipattern to newer Java developers. Maybe sometimes things need to be done for the benefit of the community even if the community won't appreciate it at first...

Answer (score 5):

From my point of view, `Optional.get()` is the code smell. Very often combined with `Optional.isPresent()`, it completely defeats the purpose and the idea of `Optional.get()`. Here's a more complete reasoning and discussion:

http://royvanrijn.com/blog/2016/04/deprecating-optional-get/

So simply don't use `Optional.get()`. If you want to return `null` for the absent value, call `Optional.orElse(null)`.

Comment: Agreed on the `.get` poor implementation. But what if, one wants to make sure that the Optional either has a value and if it doesn't he wouldn't want to continue propagating `null` ahead? (looking at throwing an Exception being such a case)

Comment: @nullpointer Normally you can achieve almost everything with `orElse`, `orElseGet`, `orElseThrow` or `map`.

Comment: As mentioned in the question as well, `orElseThrow` family does exist currently, but then I have to explicitly throw an exception there. While the newer API has a default existing(what used to be in `.get`) implementation.

Comment: @nullpointer I'm not sure what you wanted to say with your last comment. My point is, you don't necessarily need `get()` for *"what if, one wants to make sure that the Optional either has a value and if it doesn't he wouldn't want to continue propagating null ahead"*.

Comment: @nullpointer whatever scenario you have for `null`/absent value, it will probably fit in one of the mentioned methods.

Comment: simple syntax should be var x = anyOddInStreamOpotional ?? null;

Comment: @TalAvissar `Object x = optional.orElse(null);` is good enought for me.

Comment: @TalAvissar Is it valid Java syntax?

Comment: @TalAvissar Please answer my question. Is `Object x = optional??null;` valid Java syntax?

Comment: @lexicore this to me *is* the correct answer (+1), it seems like `get` will be deprecated. They probably where having guava in their mental model...

Comment: @Eugene I've read somewhere that language designers regretted `get()` in the hindsight.

Comment: @lexicore language designers is actually Stuart Marks behind this change most probably... and he is an active SO user, so we might want to ping him here, to get our response

Comment: @TalAvissar I **hate** this in C# btw (might be just me), it's like code is either screaming or wondering all the time, again, it might be just me

Answer (score 4):

An alternate method to get value of an optional instead of [`Optional.get`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#get()) (which more likely than not fails to keep up with user's expectations) is to replace it with a more verbose API introduced in JDK10 termed as **[`Optional.orElseThrow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow())**. In [author's words](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8140281) -

> `Optional.get()` is an "attractive nuisance" and is too tempting for
>   programmers, leading to frequent errors. *People don't expect a getter
>   to throw an exception.* A replacement API for `Optional.get()` with
>   equivalent semantics should be added.

```
Optional<Integer> anyOddInStream = Stream.of(2, 4, 6, 8)
                                         .filter(x -> x % 2 == 1)
                                         .findAny();
// one could be well aware of the possible exception handling while reading this 
var current = anyOddInStream.orElseThrow();
```

***Note*** :- The underlying implementation of both these APIs is same, yet the latter reads out more clearly that a ***`NoSuchElementException` would be thrown by default*** if the value is not present which inlines to the existing [`Optional.orElseThrow(Supplier<? extends X> exceptionSupplier)`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk10/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow(java.util.function.Supplier)) implementation used by consumers as an explicit alternative.